# How to keep .bat file from downloading as .txt

Tags: html, windows, download

I have a navajo web server in which I wrote the following to create a downloadable link.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>MALWARE ALERT</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY TEXT="#FF0000" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">

<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>BROWSE CAREFULLY</H1>


</p
<a href="./malware.bat" download>DO NOT CLICK</a>
</p>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Note, this is simply a fun little project I am doing.

My problem arises when I download the "malware.bat" file. What happens is my file is named malware.bat.txt which obviously creates a txt file and thus defeats the purposes and keeps the commands from being run when you click on it.

I know I can change the file back to .bat by removing the .txt file extension but I am trying to make it simple enough that someone doesn't have to do that. That way it can be downloaded and run by just clicking on it. The victim is then redirected to a website that looks malicious but isn't. So my end result needs to be when the file is downloaded it stays as a .bat file. If you have any questions as to what I am trying to do I can try and answer them.

### Note

I am not trying to actually create malware. It is supposed to be a little project to help end users learn about combatting scams, phishing attacks, and social engineering attacks. It is not malicious.

Comment: 1) the content of your batch file is totally irrelevant to the problem at hand, so better not use so much space and effort in describing it, all the while 'forcing' us to first read it and then hopefully ignore all of it, for those who even get that far. 2) it would help a lot if you told us the Webserver application that is hosting your .bat file. E.g. is it IIS or something totally different? Include version numbers, application/config settings, and anything else that may be relevant.

Comment: it is an apache version 2.2.3 server. The html code literally only contains the single line and the header. So it only has that single link you can click. I also tried uploading the file as a .cmd but I get the same result. The file gets downloaded as malware.cmd.txt. Also, I am not admin on the web server, I have a special webpage in my home directory on the redhat box that I am allowed to edit. So I cannot change some settings.

Comment: If your hosting is on `RedHat` then you should *not* tag the question `Windows`. Apart from being just wrong, you risk getting non-answers from non-Redhat-knowledgable folks (such as me)... I advise you to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47402592/edit), make it a lot shorter, and tag it properly.

Comment: I am downloading the file on windows. I don't think the problem resides on the server side of things, nor in the html code

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I tried the file on a different Windows machine and it worked properly. I was able to determine it was only the windows vm I was using. The settings for downloading it were messed up. For some reason they changed in between two of my tests. Thanks for all of the feedback.